# How to merge multiple files' history in Git/SVN

Tags: git, svn, merge, history

I am migrating an old repository from SVN to Git.  This repository contains a handful of files, but for historical reasons these exist within a subdirectory for each month.  For example:

*Nominal files*

```
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
```

*Actual layout*

```
/
|-201601
|  |- a.txt
|  |- b.txt
|  |- c.txt
|-201602
|  |- a.txt
|  |- b.txt
|  |- c.txt
|  
...
|-201807
   |- a.txt
   |- b.txt
   |- c.txt

(note no files at top level)
```

As part of the migration I'm going to remove these dated subdirectories, and we'll just have top-level files.  However, I would ideally like to merge the history from all "versions" of the file into one - that is, running `git log a.txt` in the new repo would show all the changes that were previously committed to `201807/a.txt`, `201806/a.txt`, etc.

Is there a Git command (or set of commands) that will let me merge the histories/commit from multiple files into a single file?

(If this is easier in Subversion, that's an option too; I can modify the old repostory before importing into Git.)

Comment: Git does not have file history. Git has only commits; the commits *are* the history. The commits contain files, so by extracting each commit one at a time and examining the files therein, one can *compute* a history for some set of files, but that's purely a dynamic creation of this extract-and-compute process. The history remains whatever is committed, stored in those commits.

Comment: What this means for you is that once you import the commits into Git, if the files have the same pathnames, they are the same files. You can do the renaming anywhere you like before you make the commits out of them. If you do it *after* you make the commits, you're stuck: you have to make a whole new commit subgraph that has the files under the new names. You *can* do this with `git filter-branch` but this is painful at best.

Comment: Do you want to merge all the files as well? or can you just get the last version of the file?

Comment: @torek Mmhmm, that makes sense.  So the only way to achieve this would be to mangle each commit such that the files were (allegedly) committed as the top-level path(s).  I can appreciate why that would be complicated, bordering on infeasible.

Comment: @NimeshkaSrimal I can just take the last version of each file. Though in this case both options would be the same: files are/were only modified while they were the latest version. (E.g. the `201806/a.txt` file would only be modified during June 2018; once July hit, that file would be copied to `201807/a.txt` and from that point on any changes would be applied to the latter file.  It's a silly system, which is why I'm going to get get rid of it.)

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle how about copying the latest files to the root, and running, git log --follow a.txt for example? I guess it should show you the full history since you  said you copied the file every month.

Answer (score 0):

First, regarding an import from SVN to Git, the tool to use is [SubGit](https://subgit.com) (free for a one-time import)

Second, you can consider each date folder as "branches" in SVN (with their own history), and you can follow "[Layout Changed over History](https://subgit.com/documentation/branches-mapping.html#changed_layout)", in order to instruct SubGit how to process those folders.
If this is not applicable here (because the link I mention is for *one* branch which is renamed in its SVN history), then you would need to map each folder/branch to a Git branch.